# MBED_ARM_PATH set as environment variable but doesn't exist

Tags: path, compilation, mbed

i set

```
mbed -G MBED_ARM_PATH "C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\7 2018-q2-update"
```

the latter really existing 
C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\7 2018-q2-update

Check via mbed config --list discovers

```
[mbed] Working path "C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\mbed-os-example-blinky" (program)
[mbed] Global config:
ARM_PATH=c:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\7 2018-q2-update\bin"
GCC_ARM_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\7 2018-q2-update\bin
MBED_ARM_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\7 2018-q2-update

[mbed] Local config (C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\mbed-os-example-blinky):
TOOLCHAIN=GCC_ARM
TARGET=LPC1768
```

in particular GCC_ARM_PATH ok 
but compilation

```
mbed compile --target LPC1768 --toolchain GCC_ARM --flash
```

complains

```
[mbed] Working path "C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\mbed-os-example-blinky" (program)
WARNING: MBED_ARM_PATH set as environment variable but doesn't exist
[Warning] @,: Compiler version mismatch: Have 7.3.1; expected version >= 6.0.0 and < 7.0.0
Building project mbed-os-example-blinky (LPC1768, GCC_ARM)
Scan: mbed-os-example-blinky
```

and so on.

So MBED_ARM_PATH is not valid. 
Nevertheless compilation works fine.

What is the problem??

Answer (score 1):

`MBED_ARM_PATH` should point to the installation of ARMCC (if you have it). I'd expect it's trying to find `armcc` in that folder, which it can't find, and thus marks it as invalid.

Note that when you compile against `GCC_ARM` you're not using `MBED_ARM_PATH` nor ARMCC so that's why compilation succeeds.

Note that the current supported GCC version is 6, not 7. So your results might vary.